# recursively find the closest package.json node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, path, require

I am newly with node js, and I would like to find recursively the closest package.json. Actually, continue finding package.json until will not hit it.

My folder tree

```
root/
  -contarats/
   -proto/
    some.proto
  -package.json 

"script": {
"contracts": "generate-some-contracts contracts/proto contracts",
}

const input = process.argv[2]
const settings = require(path.resolve(input, 'package.json'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for a way to iterate through directories? If so heres a synchronous function that would do that

```
function search_sync(dir) {
var results = []
var list = fs.readdirSync(dir)
list.forEach(function(file) {
    file = path.resolve(dir, file)
    filename = file.split('\\');
    filename = filename[filename.length-1]
    var stat = fs.statSync(file)
    if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) results = results.concat(search_sync(file))
    else if(filename == 'package.json')results.push(file)
})
return results
```

}

That will return an array of any files that are named package.json with their full file path. EG:

```
search_sync('./')

[C:\Users\User\MyNodeProject\package.json,
C:\Users\User\MyNodeProject\npm\someDependency\package.json,
C:\Users\User\MyNodeProject\npm\someOtherDependency\package.json]
```

Personally, I'd then break each line by their '\' character and see which one is closer to my root folder

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your tree of directories, the `package.json` file is not in `contracts/proto`, but in `contracts`. (I assume that `contaracts` is a typo.) Changing the first argument on the command line should help:

```
generate-some-contracts contracts contracts
```

Nevertheless, you ask about the recursive search for the nearest `package.json`. NPM does it, when looking for the package root. It starts in the current directory and then follows the ancestors, until it finds a `package.json`. A function reading and parsing that `package.json`, similarly to `require`, could look like this:

```js
const { readFile } = require('fs/promises')
const { join, resolve } = require('path')

async function loadPackageJson(cwd) {
  const startDir = cwd || process.env.INIT_CWD || process.cwd()
  let dir = startDir, prevDir
  do {
    try {
      const path = join(dir, 'package.json')
      const content = await readFile(path, 'utf8')
      return JSON.parse(content)
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.code !== 'ENOENT') throw err
    }
    prevDir = dir
    dir = resolve(dir, '..')
  } while (prevDir !== dir)
  throw new Error(`package.json not found in ${startDir} and its ancestors`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function findParent(dir) {
  if (fs.existsSync(path.join(dir, 'package.json'))) {
      return dir;
  }
  const parentDir = path.resolve(dir, '..');
  if (dir === parentDir) {
      return null;
  }
  return findParent(parentDir);
}

const parentDir = findParent(__dirname);

const filePath = path.normalize(`${parentDir}/package.json`);

const settings = require(filePath);
```